# Insert Incremental Number in Every Submitted Row of Google Forms in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form that submits responses to a Google Sheet. I want to add an incremental number to every submitted row in Column A, and I want this number to be based on the maximum number already present in Column A. In other words, I want each new submission to receive the next available number after the highest number in Column A. How can I achieve this using Google Apps Script?
I have prepared this code but it adds the number to prior row of the submitted row, instead of inserting the number in the submitted row.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1"); // Replace with the target sheet name
  var uniqueNumberColumnIndex = 0; // Column A

  // Calculate the row index of the form response
  var rowIndex = e.range.getRow();

  // Find the maximum unique number in column A
  var maxUniqueNumber = Math.max.apply(null, targetSheet.getRange(2, uniqueNumberColumnIndex + 1, targetSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat());

  // Increment the maximum unique number by 1 to get the next unique number
  maxUniqueNumber++;

  // Insert a new row at the calculated row index
  targetSheet.insertRowBefore(rowIndex);

  // Store the unique number in column A of the new form response row
  targetSheet.getRange(rowIndex, uniqueNumberColumnIndex + 1).setValue(maxUniqueNumber);
}
```

For example I have submitted two new rows via google forms but the script added row numbers in a separated rows before those rows as the following image:
[image]

Comment: Please update your question with the necessary data (e.g. a dummy sheets file that looks similar to your actual files) for reproduction purposes. This will enable people in the community to fully replicate your issue. From there, they can propose a solution that specifically addresses the problem. Please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 Thank you for your note. So, do I need to put the image of the encountered problem in the sheet in my question, or I need to create an example sheet and share its link here?

Comment: Just to confirm that I understand your goal correctly, is this your [expected desired result](https://imgur.com/a/THgK6CB)?

Comment: `I want to` Would you please explain _why_ you want add an incrementing value to each response, and why you want to overwrite the Timestamp. Besides my interest in your scenario, I wonder whether this might be an example of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/399653)

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 Exactly yes!

Comment: @Tedinoz Actually, those numbers are unique numbers for every submitted row, which help me to locate any specific row. For example, suppose that I may sort them in any order or delete some rows. I can find any specific row by that unique number.

Comment: `those numbers are unique numbers for every submitted row` Unless you have an avalanche of responses there is/was already a unique code = `timestamp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Suggestion

Based on your question, you wanted to assign an incremental number to all submitted data from a form into your Google spreadsheet file on Column **A**.

You may check the modified script below. This script will gather the recent data from column **A**. If it is a header (no submitted data yet), it will start counting from `0`; otherwise, the recent number will be incremented by `1` for each new submitted data.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1"); // Replace with the target sheet name
  var uniqueNumberColumnIndex = 0; // Column A

  // Get the last row of data pasted by the Google form
  var currentDataRow = e.range.getRow();
    
  //Get the most recent pasted data number
  var maxuniquenumber = typeof targetSheet.getRange(`A${currentDataRow-1}`).getValue() == 'string' ?
                        //If no data yet on the sheet, the 'maxuniquenumber' will start as 0
                        0 
                        :
                        //If there are recent data, the 'maxuniquenumber' will increment from the very recent row
                        parseInt(targetSheet.getRange(`A${currentDataRow-1}`).getValue());

  //Set the latest pasted data with the next increment number
  targetSheet.getRange(`A${currentDataRow}`).setValue((parseInt(maxuniquenumber)+1).toString());
  
}
```

---

### Demo

> [image]

### References

- [Javascript parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: @Hamed Thanks for your response. I hope this helps you in your project. Feel free to comment in case something else is missing.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your informative and great solution. I tested that and it works properly. But, as I said to Tedinoz, how about the situation that we delete some previously submitted rows?  It will generate some repetitive numbers for new rows

Answer (score 1):

Use [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) with the `onFormSubmit` trigger to identify the edited row (`var editedrow = e.range.rowStart`). Once this value is known, the calculation and update of the Unique Index is simple.

---

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1"); // Replace with the target sheet name
  
  // get the range with  submission 
  var editedrow = e.range.rowStart
  var uniqueNumberColumnIndex = editedrow-1
  Logger.log("the edited row = "+editedrow+", the unique code = "+uniqueNumberColumnIndex)
  targetSheet.getRange(editedrow,1).setValue(uniqueNumberColumnIndex).setNumberFormat("0");
}
```

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and solution. I tried it and it works fine. But, the problem is that suppose we deliberately delete some rows so as the code generates the incremental number based on the row number, it will generate repetitive numbers instead of unique numbers. That's why I supposed it may be better to find the maximum number of column A and add to it in order to generate new number. ya?

Comment: A couple of things: first, you are working with the raw data exported from the Google form into Google sheets. Many users treat this as off-limits, and they create a copy of the form responses where they do additional work.  Second: yes, you might delete a row but you didn’t mention that in the question. Third: have you tested what happens when you delete a row and a new response is received (I’m not at my pc just now). Fourth, there is nothing wrong with your approach but there are also other ways of doing this.

Comment: I made some minor changes in your code and I posted it here. In fact, I used the maximum number of column A in order to find the latest allocated number.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: `have you tested what happens when you delete a row and a new response is received` I have had the opportunity to test this and I formally acknowledge that the operation of this script, when a row is deleted, is not satisfactory and will result in duplication of the unique number. If this script is to be used, an alternative approach to determining the unique code is required.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it produces duplicate numbers as I said. That's why I used the `Math.max.apply` method. Thank you again for your response and collaboration in addressing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SputnikDrunk2  and @Tedinoz, I used their solution and made a little change on it and this is the final result.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1"); // Replace with the target sheet name

  // Get the range with the submission
  var editedRow = e.range.getRow(); // Get the edited row number
  var uniqueNumberColumnIndex = 1; // Column A for storing unique numbers

  // Find the maximum unique number in column A
  var maxUniqueNumber = Math.max.apply(null, targetSheet.getRange(2, uniqueNumberColumnIndex, targetSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat());

  // Increment the maximum unique number by 1 to get the next unique number
  maxUniqueNumber++;

  // Store the unique number in column A of the target sheet for the new form response
  targetSheet.getRange(editedRow, uniqueNumberColumnIndex).setValue(maxUniqueNumber).setNumberFormat("0");
}
```

Comment: Good to see you using Event Objects